# ssmtp issue sending mail from command line and php

Tags: php, email, sendmail, ssmtp

I am having an issue with the following statement in the command line:

```
echo 'Subject: test' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v <myemail>@gmail.com
```

it is returning the following:

```
# echo 'Subject: test' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v <email>@gmail.com
[<-] 220 mail.xen.prgmr.com ESMTP Postfix
[->] HELO host.xen.prgmr.com
[<-] 250 mail.xen.prgmr.com
[->] MAIL FROM:<root@hostname.com>
[<-] 250 2.1.0 Ok
[->] RCPT TO:<<email>@gmail.com>
[<-] 554 5.7.1 <<email>@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
sendmail: RCPT TO:<<email>@gmail.com> (554 5.7.1 <<email>@gmail.com>: Relay access denied)
```

Any clues on how to configure this to actually send out would be greatly appreciated.  Here is some of the /var/log/mail.log

```
Jun 11 02:28:47 host sendmail[29388]: alias database /etc/mail/aliases rebuilt by root
Jun 11 02:28:47 host sendmail[29388]: /etc/mail/aliases: 12 aliases, longest 10 bytes, 134 bytes total
Jun 11 02:28:48 host sm-mta[29446]: starting daemon (8.14.4): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
Jun 11 02:29:54 host sendmail[30867]: alias database /etc/mail/aliases rebuilt by root
Jun 11 02:29:54 host sendmail[30867]: /etc/mail/aliases: 12 aliases, longest 10 bytes, 134 bytes total
Jun 11 02:29:57 host sm-mta[29446]: restarting /usr/sbin/sendmail-mta due to signal
Jun 11 02:29:57 host sm-mta[30913]: starting daemon (8.14.4): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
Jun 11 02:33:09 host sendmail[31513]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 6: invalid argument to V line: "ERSIONID(\001Id: startt"
Jun 11 02:33:09 host sendmail[31513]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 7: invalid argument to V line: "ERSIONID(\001Id: autoco"
Jun 11 02:33:11 host sm-mta[30913]: restarting /usr/sbin/sendmail-mta due to signal
Jun 11 02:33:11 host sm-mta[30913]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 6: invalid argument to V line: "ERSIONID(\001Id: startt"
```

Comment: The error seems to be self explanatory, the local email server is not allowing you to send mails as a relay from this server. This is a local mail server setting.I am also not sure if <email>@gmail.com will even complete as it's not likely to be a valid destination.

Comment: The <email>@gmail.com was just a replaced name.  It is a valid email, but what in the server could be blocking the emails being relayed?

Comment: some servers have config statements that disallow relays by default, what is your local mail server running? if it's just default sendmail here's a quote from a forum post regarding config .. "Look through your sendmail.mc file and comment out the line it tells you to. Currently, sendmail is trying to contact localhost, but sendmail ain't root, so it fails. I am not at my box so I can't be more explicit than that."